# JQuery - drop shadow plugin. Custom color

Tags: jquery, colors, plugins, dropshadow

I'm using Jquery plugin DropShadow:
[web site](http://code.google.com/p/dropshadow/downloads/list)

And I want to set drop shadow color manually.

> Color is specified in the usual
>   manner, with a color name or hex
>   value.  The color parameter   does not
>   apply with transparent images.

From documentation, so, here is my code:

```
{
   ...
   color: "black",
   swap: false
}
```

It works perfect, with '#000' against 'black' it works too... But if I need shadow color, for example, red '#fff000' plugin doesn't work. I don't see any shadow. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin uses `css("background", opt.color)` to set the shadow colour - this is a correct and straightforward jQuery method which should work.

I suspect you're not specifying the dropShadow options correctly. If you could include in your question the a sample of your call to the dropShadow plugin this hypotesis could be either proved or discarded.

If you don't specify a colour, the default 'black' is used. If you instead specify the colour as '#000' (the hex representation for black) you'll not be able to tell if you're correctly specifying the desired colour and correctly overriding the in-built default.

According to the documentation, you would need to specify the options as:

```
$.dropShadow({
    color:'<your colour here>'
});
```

For red you would need to use:

```
$.dropShadow({
    color:'#f00'
});
```

Include in your question the relevant call to `$.dropShadow()` if this doesn't work.